# Inner join query - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run following query in UAT which gives me very quick result, but
Comes to production where we have about 10 Millions of records query taking too long time. Is there any better way to do it .

```
SELECT w.row_id,
       w.field_1,
       w.field_2,
       w.field_3,
       b.row_id,
       b.field_1,
       b.field_2,
       b.field_3
  FROM si.table1 w
       INNER JOIN si.table1 b
          ON     w.par_row_id = b.par_row_id
             AND w.field_1 = b.field_1
             AND w.field_3 = b.field_3
 WHERE     w.field4 = 'TEXT1'
       AND b.field4 = 'TEXT1'
       AND UPPER (w.field_2) = 'TEXT2'
       AND UPPER (b.field_2) = 'TEXT3'
```

Comment: Let me guess `UPPER(B.FIELD_2) = 'TEXT3'` => Full table scan because you don't have expression indexes?

Comment: Are other columns indexed? What does the explain plan say?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM si.table1 w INNER JOIN
     si.table1 b
     ON w.par_row_id = b.par_row_id AND
        w.field_1 = b.field_1 AND
        w.field_3 = b.field_3 AND
        w.field4 = b.field4
WHERE w.field4 = 'TEXT1' AND
      UPPER(w.field_2) = 'TEXT2' AND
      UPPER(b.field_2) = 'TEXT3';
```

You need an indexing strategy.  I would go for `table1(field4, upper(field_2), par_row_id, field_1, field_3, field4)` and `table1(par_row_id, field_1, field_3, field_4, upper(field2))`.